# Why do I get a AttributeError in this code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python 3.9

I have a class called ImageMetaData

```
class ImageMetadata(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = None
    source: Optional[str] = None
    sourcesubtype: Optional[str] = None
    filesize: Optional[int] = None
    url: Optional[str] = None
```

and a function

```
def total_filesize(images: List[ImageMetadata]):
    total = 0
    try:
        for i in images:
            total = total + i.filesize
    except BaseException as ex:
        logger.error("Caught exception trying to compute total filesize for images", exc_info=True)
    return total
```

I get an error about AttributeError:

`‘dict’ object has no attribute ‘filesize’`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"filesize"` is a dictionary key, not an attribute. Use `i["filesize"]`, not `i.filesize`. This is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the function `total_filesize`. Try like this:

```
def total_filesize(images: List[ImageMetadata]):
    total = 0
    
    try:
        for i in images:
            total = total + i["filesize"]
    
    except BaseException as ex:
        logger.error("Caught exception trying to compute total filesize for images", exc_info=True)
    return total
```